# How to connect different classes?

Tags: python, class, oop

I need to connect three classes so as to some of them could use the others' methods.

Here I show an example of how classes work. As it's seen, data is input throughout `Data` class and is manipulated by `Statistics` and `Plotting` classes.

```
class Data (object):   # This class read a file and creates a DataFrame object
    def __init__(input_data):
    def Tool:
      # [df managing operations]
      return df


class Statistics:      # This class use Data dataframe and manipulate it.
    def mean(df):
       return scalar

class Plotting:        # This class plot Data dataframe in function of Statistics outputs
    def with_colors (df, scalar):
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: it looks like they can be functions with args (eg: `colors=False`) in the same class

Comment: It's a complete program @quamrana, it would be unreadable

Comment: Yes, classes functions use plenty of args, but all classes are objects classes. None of them are childs.

Comment: why cant you just have all the functions in the same class? they are all working on the same data frame

Comment: It's just a matter of organization. There are plenty of functions and I thought grouping them by classes was a good option. Do you think I'm wrong? I thought about creating Father and Child classes or `@classmethod`, but I really don't know how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `Plotting` or `Statistics` map well to classes or instances.
They look more like libraries of functions. Otherwise you will instantiate a single `Plotting` and single `Statistics` just to call their methods on something else.

It looks like you grouped your utility methods in classes and ended up with too many methods. This is just an organization/partition problem.

If you want you can just make them modules, define functions there, import the relevant functions into the main program and pass those functions the data they need as arguments.

Also it looks you are just creating a *dataframe-like* object and adding methods to it. And reading data from somewhere looks like just another utility function.

While nothing stops you from doing those things, including inheriting from dataframe to make your own extended version, I think you are better using df objects as-is, and passing them around, to utility functions.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @progmatico. I think I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a `Data` object in `Statistics` and in `Plotting` classes' methods.